# magento2 add new grunt task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, magento2

I'm trying to create new grunt task for generating sprites for magento2. I'm using grunt-spritesmith plugin for that. In Gulpfile.js I have mapped sprite task to grunt-spritesmith in JitGrunt config:

```
require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    configPath: path.join(__dirname, configDir),
    init: true,
    jitGrunt: {
        staticMappings: {
            usebanner: 'grunt-banner',
            sprite: 'grunt-spritesmith'
        }
    }
});
```

in `dev/tools/grunt/configs` I made a config file sprite.js with contents:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    sprite: {
        all: {
            src: 'app/design/frontend/vendor/default/web/images/spritesheets/*.png',
            dest: 'app/design/frontend/vendor/default/web/images/spritesheets.png',
            destCss: 'app/design/frontend/vendor/default/web/css/source/_sprites.less'
        }
    }
};
```

But `grunt sprite` gives me

`>> No "sprite" targets found.`

Or if in different configurations I'm able to register sprite task, I'm not able to pass config with src, dest and destCss params.

Answer (score 0):

You have not include task name. This works:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    all: {
        src: 'app/design/frontend/vendor/default/web/images/spritesheets/*.png',
        dest: 'app/design/frontend/vendor/default/web/images/spritesheets.png',
        destCss: 'app/design/frontend/vendor/default/web/css/source/_sprites.less'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the boilerplate from [ravbetsky repo](https://github.com/ravbetsky/m2-grunt-spritesmith).

We did it with some changes...

## dev/tools/grunt/configs/sprite.js

```js
'use strict';

var themes  = require('./local-themes'),
    _       = require('underscore');

var themeOptions = {};

_.each(themes, function(theme, name) {
    themeOptions[name] = {
        src: 'app/design/frontend/' + theme.name + '/web/images/icons/*.png',
        dest: 'app/design/frontend/' + theme.name + '/web/images/icons-sprite.png',
        padding: 5,
        destCss: 'app/design/frontend/' + theme.name + '/web/css/source/lib/_icons_spritesmith.less',
        imgPath: '../images/icons-sprite.png',
        algorithm: 'binary-tree',
        cssVarMap: function (sprite) {
            sprite.name = 'icon-sprite-' + sprite.name;
        }
    };
});

module.exports = themeOptions;
```

## dev/tools/grunt/tasks/sprite.js

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    'use strict';
    // Load in `grunt-spritesmith`
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-spritesmith');
};
```

## How it works

The icons would be saved under `<Theme>/web/images/icons/*.png`, and would be available as `<Theme>/web/images/icons-sprite.png`.

To regenerate the sprite you would run `grunt sprite:<themename>`, where `<themename>` is the name of your theme, as specified in `dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes.js`. See [official doc](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/debug/) for more details about local-themes and generic grunt/less configuration.

To regenerate the css from the updated less files, just run `grunt less:<themename>`.

Note: you must have installed the dependencies (npm install) and also have spritesmith as one (npm install grunt-spritesmith) before doing these steps.